# Installing avahi-daemon on ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server

I'm currently trying to install avahi on a ubuntu server (20.04). I've tried installing the package multiple times, but the install stops with an exception every time. The error is: 
"Failed to open file '/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf': no such file or directory". Do I need to create this file manually or is there something else i need to do?

Comment: Try `sudo touch /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`. This will create an empty config file. Probably won't be of much use if the process has to read from it though. But it doesn't hurt to try anyway.

Comment: Actually did work! I just copied the avahi conf file over from another working machine now, seems to be working fine!

Comment: Maybe you should then post it as an answer to your question... But I believe there should be more to the solution than just that copy... Try checking the differences between the non-working and the working files.